# Search engine split

Tags: regex

I am trying to improve a search engine and when I search

```
key1 [key2 key3] key4
```

I need to return 3 strings

```
key1
key2 key3
key4
```

Can you please help me with the regular expression for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grabbing the elements inside the square brackets first then any other words.

```
(\[[\w\s]*\]|\w+)
```

This will return each element as you require (will need leading and trailing square brackets removed).

You can test that on [regxr](https://regexr.com/) and see if that will match as you need.